# Fedora Server 25 firewall issue. Ports 22, 80, 443 blocked at each boot, have to stop firewalld

Tags: fedora, saltstack, nextcloud

I setup Fedora Server 25 in a VM and [used SaltStack to install NextCloud via this walk-thru](https://mangolassi.it/topic/12869/install-nextcloud-11-on-fedora-25-with-saltstack). The issue I am having is the firewall is too restrictive and is blocking ports 22, 80 and 443. Per the walk-thru creator's suggestion, I edited the SaltStack "nextcloud.sls" file as follows, but it did not help:
`#line108
FedoraServer:
  firewalld.present:
    - name: FedoraServer
    - block_icmp:
      - echo-reply
      - echo-request
    - default: False
    - masquerade: True
    - ports:
      - 22/tcp
      - 80/tcp
      - 443/tcp
      - 9090/tcp`

What can I do to open these ports so I don't have to keep stopping the firewalld service at each boot? Thank you.
EDIT: So, even after removing `- firewalld` from the nextcloud.sls script (under `install_network_packages: pk.installed:`the firewall is *still* starting up and blocking all the ports I need. **There must be something else in Fedora Server that is overriding the SaltStack script and enabling the firewall...??**

Comment: Will this help ? I am not familiar with fedora firewall salt config 
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/firewall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know SaltStack, but you should be able to permanently open the required ports via `firewall-cmd`. For example, to permanently open `ssh`, try the following:

`firewall-cmd --add-service=ssh; firewall-cmd --add-service=ssh --permanent`

For enabling ICMP and the other services:

```
firewall-cmd --remove-icmp-block=echo-request
firewall-cmd --remove-icmp-block=echo-request --permanent
firewall-cmd --remove-icmp-block=echo-reply
firewall-cmd --remove-icmp-block=echo-reply --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=9090/tcp
firewall-cmd --add-port=9090/tcp --permanent
```

I suggest you to first try *without* the permanent rules. If all works correctly, you can issue the permanent rules and reboot the machine.

Comment: Great, this worked for SSH! Thank you! Any chance you know how I can enable PING (ICMP echo-replies) too?

Comment: I've edited my answer, give it a look.

Answer (score -2):

Why have the firewall on the same server as NextCloud instance? Why not just control port traffic from your network firewall? You could just create a zone for that server and control what goes in and out of it from network level.

Comment: 1) this doesn't answer the OP's question 2) defense in depth is very much a desirable thing.

Comment: Just as EEAA said, it's for layered security. We of course have a perimeter firewall and I "could" run this VM without a software firewall, but I'd much prefer not to.